# How to consume RPC encoded WSDL in JAX-WS 2+

Tags: xml, wsdl, jax-ws, apache-axis

We are trying to consume encoded wsdl in our application. Tried using Apache Axis 1.4 but it is now not in use and so it has some security flaws so can not use it. Can someone help with some other alternative?